# Xcode 6.4 sync to app store from new machine after old lost

Tags: ios-appstore, xcode, developer-program

About a year ago, I have developed an iOS app on a Mac machine and synced it to the app store.

That machine has lost, so I got a new one connected to my Apple developer id. I have recovered my work and changed a few things in the code.

But when I try to resync the app, I get the attached warning.

[image: Error while sync to app store]

From a quick search on Google I realized that I needed to export my developer profile from my previous machine and import it on the new machine.

Because I don't have access to that machine I need to somehow recreate the developer profile.

Any idea for how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the old developer profile any more because you don't want to concurrently develop on two machines. Therefore, you can revoke your certificate and generate a new one to install on this machine. Go to the [Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/account/overview.action) → Certificates, click the + button and generate a new development certificate.

Comment: i tryed the Solution above, but still not working.

we found that 2 diffrente developer profile built the app, do you think that here is connection? and if so how to solve it?